# I have a tiny problem

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, recommendations

I have a <strike>huge</strike> tiny problem! The problem is that I cannot post a question on this site which does not automatically get put on hold!

My problem began when I tried to ask which tool I should use to develop apps, i.e which is the most commonly used one...

I have tried debugging this problem by editing the text, phrasing and question. So far all my debugging ended in syntax errors, and I cannot get my question to run properly.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks greatly!

Comment: Your problem is that your question is not suitable for stack exchange sites.  Recommendations are opinion based and also stuck in a certain time.

Comment: A huge problem would be a flooded basement. What you have is a tiny problem which can be resolved by reading the ["what's on-topic" help page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: given your command in English, you could "buy" an access to [specialized debugger](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard "Programmers Whiteboard chat room") by suggesting [10 good, thorough edits](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat "accepted edit gives 2 rep points, total 20 points suffice to participate in chat") to others posts

Comment: I think you can try to asking directly in the chat room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @MetaFight - spot on!

Comment: Thank you for that, the whats on topic page does not, however, answer my question, only explains that my question should never be asked. So how about if I ask simply: Is Embarcadero RAD studio a commonly used tool for app development, or is very few using it (meaning that there is very little help to find online if I should need it) Its a simple yes or no question

Answer (score 10):

Recommendations are off topic on P.SE.  There is a long history to this on both P.SE and Stack Overflow.  For some of the P.SE history see [this search](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=recommendation).

We have a specific close reason for off topic for questions asking for some software recommendation.

> Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This is what you need to look at.  We don't do recommendations.  There is, however, a (currently private beta) Stack Exchange site just for recommendations - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations - once this is in pubic beta you could ask such a question there.

Furthermore, consider that questions of the use of a given tool is also off topic on P.SE, but on topic on Stack Overflow.  If you pick a tool you *may* be able to ask and get an answer for "how to use that tool to do XYZ" on Stack Overflow.